# Any entry level DSLR going to be released in 2013 by Canon

Tags: canon, dslr

are you aware of any entry-level budget DSLR which is going to be released by Canon in 2013? In case if you have heard any news/report. I tried googling to no avail.

Comment: Please see the [faq]. Crystal-ball questions about new models are out of scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many "Canon rumors" type websites.
I could suggest a few BUT your googling and mine would be likely to be about as effective in this case.

Nobody who really knows tells.
Nobody who tells really knows.

The answer is "Yes. Of course. But, why do you care?".
Canon already make a number of entry level DSLRs.
 They will continue to come out with new models.
 The lowest cost ones will be about as low cost as they can make while making at least some profit.
The new ones will be somewhat better than the old ones in many but not all areas.
This is always the case.

It is unlikely that there is anything so special coming that it is worth waiting a long  time for if you aim is to start taking great pictures asap.

Just do it!

---

Flame war territory:

[flamesuit = 1]

If you want the best performing camera optically for the $ look at Nikon and Sony.
Both use Sony sensors in most or all cases.
(And mattdm notes that
"Pentax also uses ... Sony sensors and generally presents great performance for the money.")

Sony seem to have a slight edge in sensor performance per $ at present.
This will possibly not be the case long term.
BUT there are other factors apart from raw sensor performance.
If you care about lenses, ergonomics, battery life, weather proofing, cost, response time from shutter press, response time from power up, buffer size, or any of many other things then
[**Here is one of the better places to look for information**](http://www.dpreview.com/camerareviews/) (DPReview website).

[flamesuit = 1 ] ; still :-)

.

Comment: @mattdm - your comment melded with answer